# Help with calculated columns

Tags: list, column, calculated-column

I have two columns in my SharePoint list called  name and email, So I want to have the name be the display name and have the value of the email.

So when a users selects a name he or she won't see the email because the name will be the display name with the value of the email.

Can this be done in calculated column?

Comment: Can you please brief it with example?

Answer (score 0):

I think so.

Best approach is to read (all) SharePoint Formula Functions (there are not that many), read the Description & examples and see what matches your need

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated column and use a formula like this

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href='mailto:",[email],"'>",[Name],"</a>")
```

Comment: I tried it and its not what I was looking for , but thank you for your help

Comment: maybe you can explain on what you were looking for? a screen shot could help!